# Dynamically change config setting kafka in C#

Tags: c#, apache-kafka

I am very new to Apache Kafka. I work on C#.NET /Windows platform .
I was able to play with config settings for Kafka and send and receive message using Command prompt.

Using https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/producer-and-consumer-for-kafka-in-.net-an-exploration.html
I ran the c# program and was able to Produce and Receive message. 
Qn1: I am trying to read a json file and based on number of rows in json file , Is there a way of dynamically changing value of num.partitions value from C#?

Thanks
MR

Answer (score 1):

I do not see `num.partitions` in that link

But sure, you could read a property file, or make a timer to close and re-create any producer or consumer object.

But while a producer or consumer is running, there is no straightforward way to re-configure its properties.

It doesn't look like the `Kafka-Net` library has been updated since 2016, you can rather use the [`confluent-dotnet-kafka`](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet) client.